# List Index Out of Range on Python. Nothing works

Tags: python

I have already reviewed multiple threads with similar answers to my question. Nothing seems to be working no matter what I try.

I am trying to create 100 random numbers, and put those random numbers into a list. However I keep getting

```
File "E:\WorkingWithFiles\funstuff.py", line 17, in randNumbs
    numbList[index]+=1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code is:

```
def randNumbs(numbCount):
    numbList=[0]*100
    i=1
    while i < 100:
        index = random.randint(1,100)
        numbList[index]+=1
        i+=1
    print (numbList)
    return (numbList)
```

After reviewing multiple threads and tinkering around I cannot seem to get an answer.

Before I continue here is the scope of the project:
I have a .txt file thats a dictionary with however many words are in it. First, I write a function to calculate how many words are in the .txt file. Second, I generate 100 random numbers between 1 and the amount of words in the .txt file. Lastly I need to create a .txt file that prints

```
"Number   Word"
 120      Bologna
```

and so on. I am having trouble generating the random numbers. If anybody has any idea on why my list index is out of range and how to help, all help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: the .txt file is 113k words long

Comment: Python uses 0-based indexing.  A list with 100 elements has indices 0 - 99.

Answer (score 3):

You made a list of size 100 here:

```
numbList=[0]*100
```

Your problem is that you create indexes from 1 to 100 when you should be accessing indexes 0-99. Given a list of size `n`, the valid list indexes are `0` to `n-1`

Change your code to

```
index = random.randint(0,99)
```

Comment: `i` isn't being used as a list index. It's the result of `randint` that's being used as an index.

Comment: I tried fixing that and I was partially successful until it only started working half the time.
113809
[0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1]

Comment: And then I would get >>> 
================== RESTART: E:\WorkingWithFiles\funstuff.py ==================
113809
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\WorkingWithFiles\funstuff.py", line 26, in <module>
    randNumbs(numbCount)
  File "E:\WorkingWithFiles\funstuff.py", line 17, in randNumbs
    numbList[index]+=1
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an off-by-one error. randint will return numbers 1 to 100, while your list has indexes 0 to 99.

Also, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
def randNumbs(numbCount):
    return [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(numbCount)]
```

Comment: Your rewrite isn't doing the same thing as the OP's code.

Comment: I ran this code and it crashed my computer. I should probably mention the .txt file is 113k words long

Comment: That shouldn't crash your computer!  No application should.  Which OS are you using, and how did a crash?  Or did you mean it crashed your process?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem a little differently:

```
from random import sample

SAMPLE_SIZE = 100

# load words
with open("dictionary.txt") as inf:
    words = inf.read().splitlines()   # assumes one word per line

# pick word indices
# Note: this returns only unique indices,
#   ie a given word will not be returned twice
num_words = len(words)
which_words = sample(range(num_words), SAMPLE_SIZE)
# Note: if you did not need the word indices, you could just call
#   which_words = sample(words, SAMPLE_SIZE)
# and get back a list of 100 words directly

# if you want words in sorted order
which_words.sort()

# display selected words
print("Number   Word")
for w in which_words:
    print("{:6d}   {}".format(w, words[w]))
```

which gives something like

```
Number   Word
   198   abjuring
  2072   agitates
  2564   alevin
  6345   atrophies
  8108   barrage
  9155   begloom
 10237   biffy
 11078   bleedings
 11970   booed
 14131   burials
 14531   cabal
# etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I’ve tried to fix your code. Explanations in comments.

```
import random

def rand_numbs(numb_count):

    # this will generate a list of length 100
    # it will have indexes from 0 to 99

    numbList = [0] * 100

    # dont use a while loop...
    # when a for loop will do

    for _ in range(numb_count):

    # randint(i, j) will generate a number
    # between i and j both inclusive!
    # which means that both i and j can be generated

        index = random.randint(0, 99)

    # remember that python lists are 0-indexed
    # the first element is nlist[0]
    # and the last element is nlist[99]
        numbList[index] += 1

    print (numbList)
    return (numbList)
```